# In Java, what is the actual class for a superclass variable that is referencing a subclass reference?

Tags: java, inheritance, reference

I am still new to Java, and I am a bit confused with how Java is treating a superclass variable that is referencing a subclass reference.
I have two classes:

```
public class Animal{
}
public class Dog extends Animal{
}
```

And then I created a Run class as below:

```
public class Run{
    public void get_dog (Dog a){
        System.out.println("got a dog");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a_animal = new Dog(); //Create a Animal variable with Dog class
        Run test = new Run();
        System.out.println(a_animal.getClass().getSimpleName());
        test.get_dog(a_animal); //This will not run
    }
}
```

The getClass().getSimpleName() tells me that a_animal's class is Dog. But the test.get_dog(a_animal) will not run, saying get_name() will only take a Dog class instead of a Animal class. So what exactly is the class for a_animal?

Comment: The _declared type_ is `Animal` but the _actual type_ is `Dog`.

Comment: And _declared_ types rule in Java, unless you write an explicit **type cast**, as in  `test.get_dog((Dog)a_animal);`

Comment: You can refer to the explanation and the answer i've given below @Wayne Yiquan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 test.get_dog((Dog)a_animal);
```

the `get_dog()` method is expecting a `Dog` object as the parameter. Since your `a_animal` is first initialized as a `Animal` class, you need to explicitly typecast it as a `Dog` object, so that it knows that your `a_animal` is a `Dog` object.

Check out: Polymorphism and Type casting in Java

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here is one of static typing versus dynamic typing.  At compile-time, the `a_animal` variable is known to the compiler as an `Animal`.  Trying to use it as a `Dog` fails because the compiler knows that not all Animal instances are dogs (i.e. Animal is not Dog, and is not a subclass of Dog).

At runtime, the `a_animal` will reference a Dog, and that call would work.  To see how this plays out, change `test.get_dog(a_animal)` to `test.get_dog((Dog) a_animal)` - this `(Dog)` is a cast that tells the compiler to treat `a_animal` as a Dog type.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you should pass an Animal object to get_dog method and not a Dog object. What you have tried is called upcasting . A reference variable of Parent class refers to the object of Child class as below.

```
 Animal a_animal = new Dog();
```

[image]

I've re-written you a code to understand the concept as below

```
public class Animal {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("An animal is running");
    }
}


public class Dog extends Animal {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("Dog is running in 20kmph");
    }
}



public class Run{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a_animal = new Dog(); //Creating a reference variable of Animal class by referring to Dog class (upcasting)
        a_animal.run();//
    }
}
```

Below is the result

[image]

**Explanation**

We are calling the run method by the reference variable of Parent class. Since it refers to the subclass object and subclass method overrides the Parent class method, the subclass method is invoked at runtime.

The method invocation is determined by the JVM and not the compiler, it is known as runtime polymorphism.